# Python List Bracket Removal

Tags: python, list, procedure

So I am trying to add a list of ticker symbols from a CSV file into a python list.

The CSV File looks like this:

```
AAPL
XOM
EMC
```

When working with the stockList[].  How do I remove the [' '] brackets and quote marks?

My code is below:

```
stockList = []
csvReader = csv.reader(open('tickers.csv','rb'), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
for row in csvReader:
    stockList.append(row)

for item in stockList:
    print repr(item)
```

For example when the code above is ran it outputs:

```
['AAPL']
['XOM']
['EMC']
```

Comment: If it's just a list of symbols, `csv` is not appropriate; just read the lines in the file.

Comment: That's not a CSV file.  CSV would have "comma separated values".  You've just got a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like CSVReader is returning a list of rows. Modify your code in this way.

```
for row in csvReader:
    row = "".join(row)
    stockList.append(row)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `readlines` if your data is just a text file with a line-break after each symbol

```
fh = open('tickers.txt', 'rb')
stockList = [x.rstrip('\n') for x in fh]
```

That will return you:

```
['AAPL', 'XOM', 'EMC']
```

Much easier.

Comment: Actually it will return `['AAPL\n', 'XOM\n', 'EMC\n']`, maybe you want something like `stockList = map(str.rstrip, fh)`

Comment: @NiklasB.: except that wouldn't work for Unicode data (though I recognise you won't get that in stock symbols); a more Pythonic solution is `stocks = [x.rstrip('\n') for x in fh]`.

Comment: @Chris: You're right. For the record: The list comprehension is better because it uses the appropriate `rstrip` method for the type of `x`.

Comment: True.  I was more pointing out that his file isn't CSV and it's much easier than he's making.  Question updated.

Comment: @tkone would `stockList = [x.rstrip() for x in fh.readlines()]` work better? I thought windows had some weird line-endings, like '\r\n'.

Comment: @Andbdrew user doesn't say what platform they're on, but yeah, if you're on windows AND it's a windows formatted text file you'll need to remove both characters.